# Wicket model's field to panel's model

Tags: java, wicket

I have a question in wicket models. Can't write down all code becouse of company privacies, there is only part that I think is important. My POJO java class is. Period is 2 LocalDates type objets.

```
Class MyClass {
   private List<Period> periods = new ArrayList<>();

   public void setPeriods(List<Periods> periods) {
       this.periods = periods;
   }

   public List<Period> getPeriods() {
       return this.periods;
   }
}
```

For List I have special panel with dataTable, which allow to add and delete period.

```
Class MyPanel extends Panel {
    public MyPanel(String id, IModel<List<Period>> model) {
        super(id, model);
    }

    void onInitialize() {
        Form<List<Period>> form = new Form<>("myPeriodsForm", model);
        rebuildTable(form, null); // here is the code for dataTable building and updating via ajax(here is null).          
    }
}
```

I'm creating webPage with model based on MyClass POJO, and inserting this model to form.

```
CompoundPropertyModel propertyModel = new CompoundPropertyModel(getModel());
Form<MyClass> form = new Form<>("myForm", propertyModel);
form.add(new MyPanel("myPanel", propertyModel.bind("periods")));
form.add(new AjaxLinkButton("save", this::store));

....

private MyClass getObject() {
    return form.getModelObject();
}

private void store(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
    myClassService.save(getObjetct()); // here is myClassService is autowired Spring Bean which storing object in database;
}
```

when I'm creating WebPage with not empty List periods, then I can see periods of dates in dataTable, I can add new period, can delete period. I did debug and saw that model in panel is showing all periods which I've added, so working as should. But when I'm trying to save object, by clicking on save button then form.getModelObject() returning empty List, even if object hasn't been empty when had been inserted.

I tryed to change model inserting to panel I wrote:

```
    CompoundPropertyModel propertyModel = new CompoundPropertyModel(getModel());
    Form<MyClass> form = new Form<>("myForm", propertyModel);
    form.add(new MyPanel("myPanel", new CompoundPropertyModel(form.getModelObject().getPeriods())));// you see there now I'm getting List<> and creating compound model
    form.add(new AjaxLinkButton("save", this::store));
```

And now by clicking ob save button It's getting all periods from panel as it should. 
I can't understand why is it happening.

I realized that on panel at some time moments updateModel() happening, and by wicket code in FormComponent class:

```
public void updateModel() {
    this.setModelObject(this.getConvertedInput());
}
```

so, I've override updateModel method:

```
@Override
public void updateModel() {
    setConvertedInput(getModelObject());
    super.updateModel();
}
```

It's mean that convertedInput is not changing when panel's and form's model changing.

I have now the idea why the updateModel had been called, I've wrote here AjaxLinkButton, but actually in the code using our own buttons, which extends AjaxButton and submit form.

Comment: Seems to me your MyPanel is messing up the list, since it works when you retrieve the periods upfront. Sorry, this is just a guess.

Comment: looks like problem coused by panel's model updating, I've added @Override empty method updateModel, and now it's returning List of periods

Comment: A normal panel does not change its model. Are you using a FormComponentPanel somewhere?

Comment: no, I'm using usual form on panel

Comment: and also form on webpage, tree like this page:form:panel:form

Comment: maybe it's becouse I'm using CompoundPropertyModel on webPage form and inserting CompoundPropertyModel to panel with form?

Comment: A stacktrace would be helpful: Put a breakpoint on your #updateModel() and put the stracktrace somewhere so we can take a look.

Comment: Made an breakPoint on updateModel, it's calling when I save object to database and saw this in debug stacktrace: DEBUG org.apache.wicket.model.LoadableDetachableModel - loaded transient object.... might be it's the reason why updateModel has been calling

Comment: That's normal: when a new value is pushed into a model, the former value is retrieved first to compare the two, Question remains: which FormComponent is trying to change the list in the model - check what #rebuildTable() is doing.

Comment: When new value is pushed into model updateModel hasn't calling, it's calling when get and save POJO object.

Comment: I have now the idea why the updateModel had been called, I've wrote here AjaxLinkButton, but actually in the code using our own buttons, which extends AjaxButton and submit form.